# MailKit GetSubfolders

Tags: imap, mailkit

I am using Mailkit GetSubfolders method which emits this Request/Response to the server

```
C: A00000005 LIST "" "INBOX.%" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN STATUS (UIDVALIDITY))
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.kkkk
S: * STATUS INBOX.kkkk (UIDVALIDITY 1491227899)
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Archive
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.spam
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Sent
S: * STATUS INBOX.Sent (UIDVALIDITY 1491227490)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Junk
S: * STATUS INBOX.Junk (UIDVALIDITY 1491227488)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Drafts
S: * STATUS INBOX.Drafts (UIDVALIDITY 1491227487)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Trash
S: * STATUS INBOX.Trash (UIDVALIDITY 1491227603)
S: A00000005 OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

However I noticed Outlook and other mail client shows more folders for my account that I am getting with MailKit GetSubfolders. In particular INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg folder. I executed LIST "" "INBOX.*" (changing % to *) and I see this time the server returns the missing folder (see below). My question is how to get to INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg folder using MailKit methods?

```
C: A00000005 LIST "" "INBOX.*" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN STATUS (UIDVALIDITY))
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.kkkk
S: * STATUS INBOX.kkkk (UIDVALIDITY 1491227899)
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Archive
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Archive.000
S: * STATUS INBOX.Archive.000 (UIDVALIDITY 1491227889)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Archive.aaaaa
S: * STATUS INBOX.Archive.aaaaa (UIDVALIDITY 1491227877)
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.spam
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.spam.666
S: * STATUS INBOX.spam.666 (UIDVALIDITY 1491227878)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.spam.nnhnhn
S: * STATUS INBOX.spam.nnhnhn (UIDVALIDITY 1491227870)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.spam.test
S: * STATUS INBOX.spam.test (UIDVALIDITY 1491227856)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Sent
S: * STATUS INBOX.Sent (UIDVALIDITY 1491227490)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Junk
S: * STATUS INBOX.Junk (UIDVALIDITY 1491227488)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Drafts
S: * STATUS INBOX.Drafts (UIDVALIDITY 1491227487)
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.Trash
S: * STATUS INBOX.Trash (UIDVALIDITY 1491227603)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg
S: * STATUS INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg (UIDVALIDITY 1491227900)
S: A00000005 OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my question. ImapClient.GetFolders is returning all the folders in the namespace including the missing INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg

Answer (score 0):

You are meant to call `GetSubfolders()` on each folder returned by `GetSubfolders()` if you want to recurse.

The problem with using `*` is that on some IMAP servers (*cough* UW.IMAPd *cough*), if the user has symlinks, the server response will never end because it does not properly detect symlink recursion.

Comment: Well... I guess it is better not to support servers like UW.IMAPd than having folders that are not visible in my application (but are visible in other popular email clients). The fact that other email clients are showing those folders lead me to the conclusion that they use
LIST INBOX.* rather than LIST INBOX.%, because I can't find any other way Dovecot to report this folder INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg.